# How to identify prestashop Friendly URL active or deactivate in controller file.

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to know how to get the prestashop **Friendly URL** is active or not in my custom module controller.
[image]

Is there any core function or any other method to get those detail in controller file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes by getting the `PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS` configuration.

```
$friendy_url_active = Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS');
```